# Talk in Stack Overflow chat

Tags: support, stack-overflow, chat, privileges

I am getting an error when I try to join the chat, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It's not you, it's us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It's not strictly necessary, but if you'd like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: "If you'd like to give us additional information" > A good start would be the browser + version you use, for example. Because right now I can just load that page.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell [his chat profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5958045/organicnz) is broken, it's something with the account itself, often happening after a merge. (chat never played nicely with merge.)

Comment: BTW, your real name is still visible in your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1145147), you might want to change it by synchronizing the network profile with one of your other profiles on SE.

Answer (score 1):

My deep apologies, I haven't checked out extensions' settings on Chrome initially. `NoScript` and `Ghostery` were blocking it. Looks like it's opening now :)

Comment: That is weird. What do you see when going to [your chat profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5958045/organicnz) then?

Comment: I can see the rooms when go through the this link: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/
Your link pops the same error.

Comment: And can you actually chat? If so it will be quite the miracle, since you don't have a "living" chat profile on SO.

Comment: Strange, when I press "log in" it passes forward me to https://stackoverflow.com/ where I already logged in and see "Top Questions".

Comment: Yes, something is broken in your chat profile, your account was merged at some point, and the chat profile is "stuck" on the old account which is gone... it's pretty common, and only way to fix it is reset the chat profile. Not sure who can do it, maybe only SE staff.